# ASP.NET C# Set OnSelectedIndexChanged from Code Behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind, dropdownbox

Im trying to set the SelectedIndexChanged from the code behind of a Web Forms application. I have a variable amount of dropdowns being added onto the page from the database and need a method to trigger each time one of the dropdowns change.

Im currently trying:

```
ddlProductCause.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(ddlProductCause_Changed);
ddlProductCause.ID = "ddlProductCause_" + row["item_id"].ToString();
ddlProductCause.AutoPostBack = true;
```

and...

```
public void ddlProductCause_Changed(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
```

But I have no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you subscribe all of your dropdowns?

Comment: I set each drop down with a unique id?

Comment: Please post you `Page_Load` method code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Event Argument may cause this, use `EventArgs`

```
protected void ddlProductCause_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e){
   //to get id
   DropDownList ddl=sender as DropDownList;
   //ddl.Id <---Access property like this.
 }
```

Comment: Brilliant, this is triggering the event, how will I be able to get the id of the drop down that triggered the method? ie << ddlProductCause.ID = "ddlProductCause_" + row["item_id"].ToString(); >>

Comment: this appears to be failing at getting the id line - object set to null.

Comment: `ddl` object is null?

Comment: ddl sender is null, it appears to be referencing a different object in the page. Can I add an extra parameter into the ddlProductCase_Changed(object sender, eventargs e, int id)??

Comment: There is problem with casting,need to cast like this DropDownList ddl=sender as DropDownList; this is appropriate way.

Comment: Fantastic, much appreciated!!